# create oracle connection using function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to create a function for oracle connection which will take the parameters as mentioned in below code, but seems some issue...

could anyone please help in understanding how it can be corrected and what i'm missing here?

```
import cx_Oracle

def sqlconnect(user,passwd,SID, query):
    connStr = cx_Oracle.connect('user/passwd@SID')
    cursor = connStr.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sqlconnect('user','password','XEE','select * from dual')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *issues* are you facing?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: when i execute the above code on my Linux box , it goes into a hung state with no output or any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `user/passwd@SID` is not a valid connect string. Unless `XEE` is a tnsnames.ora entry you need to reference the host and service name in your connect string. You probably want something like this, instead:

```
def sqlconnect(user, passwd, dsn, query):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=passwd, dsn=dsn)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = "my_host_name"
    service_name = "XEE"
    conn_string = f"{host}/{service_name}"
    sqlconnect("user", "password", conn_string, "select * from dual")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below link which helps you to understand how Python connects to Oracle db and you are missing TNS entry or full service JDBC URL and below are some samples:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpythononprem.html

https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-Scripting-for-the-Future.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there's also another way by using `f-strings`:

```
import cx_Oracle

def sqlconnect(user,passwd,dsn, query):
    connStr = cx_Oracle.connect(f'{user}/{passwd}@{dsn}')
    cursor = connStr.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'{query}')
    return cursor.fetchall()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sqlconnect('user','password','localhost/SID','select * from dual')
```